# How to apply function to pandas index value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe df

```
                   c1     c2  
name       sample
person1    a1      aaa    AAA  
           b1      bbb    BBB  
           c1      ccc    CCC  
person2    d1      ...
```

I want to apply any function to all index (level 1) values. Say, just to give an example, remove the last letter from the index (they are strings), by this function:

```
def remove_last_letter(x)
    x = x[:-1]
    return x
```

to get this:

```
                   c1     c2  
name       sample
person1    a       aaa    AAA  
           b       bbb    BBB  
           c       ccc    CCC  
person2    d       ...
```

How to call such a function?

Comment: Basically you can try either of the methods suggested in the dupe but the pandas suggested method is to use `set_levels`

Comment: I can (kind of) see that the duplicate answer is solving a similar problem that I am. However, the answer is not very well explained (at least for a beginner). Can you turn the duplicate answer into a more general form here? Something that operates any function on all level 1 index values.

Comment: Basically to solve your specific question do this `df.index = df.index.set_levels(df.index.get_level_values(1).str.replace('\d+',''), level=1)`. You can get a specific index level labels using `.get_level_values` and pass the level value, this returns an `IndexArray`, then do whatever you want and assign back using `set_levels`